# Vuejs read all files under a folder

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I have following files under a folder

```
Locale
 -> Test1
    - abc.png
    -cde.png
 -> Test2
    -egf.png
```

i need all images from this folder. I am using below code to retrieve this. However, it's not working. May I know how can I read these images?

```
require.context('../Locale', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.png$/i)
```

Comment: can you try this require.context('/Locale', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.png$/i)

Comment: @MHFuad it does not work. Path of local is correct. Its the subfolder I cant read from my code

Comment: you are correct, you need to loop over subfolders

Comment: @MHFuad any sample?

Answer (score 0):

Add below configuration

```
require.context(directory, useSubdirectories = true, regExp = /^\.\/.*$/, mode = 'sync');
```

you can see the documentation [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/)